# Best Way to Sprite Images?

Tags: css, css-sprites

I am now getting to the point that I want to sprite the images on www.trailbehind.com.

Most of the images are loaded by JavaScript functions, and I have lots of little images such as the map icons.

Is there any software that supports this? I know that you can use Django-sprites if your images are in Django templates. And you can use GWT similarly, if you want to write some Java code.

What's the best way to go about this for a website that is Python/Django with a Javascript front-end? I never show any HTML unless the user has JavaScript turned off.

Comment: Your above-mentioned site, (in IE6) with a browser window height of 660, fails to display the full navigation or to provide scrollbars - somewhat frustrating and ultimately worthless.

Comment: @Traingamer wow, you're using IE6?!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [Glue](http://gluecss.com/). It's an open-source command line tool to generate css sprites.

Answer (score 4):

There is an [online sprite generator.](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/) This can help the process greatly.

Answer (score 1):

[SpriteMe](http://spriteme.org/) is a great option, it works as a bookmarklet so you can easily run it on any site you have to see the potential gains.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac, you can have tools for this. These tools are ordering sprites in an efficient way and generates the possible minimum sprite sheet. Also they are generating CSS output for you automatically. Thus, you don't need to fight with coordinates or counting pixels. You can use [Sprite Master](http://www.mobinodo.com/spritemaster) for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna generate tighter sprites output, try [ZeroSprites](http://zerosprites.com/).

[ZeroSprites](http://zerosprites.com/) uses VLSI floorplanning algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://draeton.github.com/stitches/ is an HTML5 online application.(To be opened with a modern browser)

You just have to drag and drop your images and you can generate the sprite image and the css code to use in your style sheet.