# Best css sprite available in online?

Tags: css, css-sprites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Way to Sprite Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933165/best-way-to-sprite-images)

Hi i have been using this http://spritegen.website-performance.org for css sprites generator. But it not worth great. I have seen sites like yahoo,bing.google they used css sprite very great and upto the high level. where to get the css sprite generator like that in online. Moreover the image is totally compressed and minimized. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always created sprites myself with Gimp.

Gimp's compression is the best I've seen. I get smaller file sizes than Photoshop and other stuff I've used.

http://www.gimp.org/

---

Edit:
Other online generators

- http://csssprites.org/
- http://csssprites.com/
- http://css-sprit.es/
- http://drupal.org/project/sprites

Comment: but is there possibility to find css-sprite online.Im using windows.

Comment: Gimp is free and works on the Windows platform.

Comment: @Jay you'll obtain the best quality by making your own in a graphics program, as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

For generating files local applications may result better and gives you much control on generating sprite sheets.

I use [Sprite Master Web](http://www.mobinodo.com/spritemasterweb) for generating my sprite sheets. It exports CSS file also.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, but on Windows or Linux. :-/