# I need a recommendation on a great sprite generator

Tags: html, css, sprite, css-sprites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Way to Sprite Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933165/best-way-to-sprite-images)

I'm looking for a sprite generator. There are a ton of them out there and I need a recommendation. Ideally I would like it to generate a sprite and a css files with class names that I can just apply to anything that needs the image.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to use css with normal images and then use the bookmarklet available at http://spriteme.org/ to convert it one or more sprites.